# How to change the size of this gallery?

Tags: jquery, css, frontend, swiper.js, web-frontend

I have this for an example http://codepen.io/moransh4/pen/aZOeNO

How can i change the size of the images to be :

```
width: 370px;
height: 200px;
```

And i see only 3 images (slides per view) ?

Eventually i want it to be like that:

[image]

I use this http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.V1UqS5F9600 for swiper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
<div class="teaser-gallery__slider js-teaser-gallery-slider" data-slides-per-view="5">
```

for this:

```
<div class="teaser-gallery__slider js-teaser-gallery-slider" data-slides-per-view="3">
```

change the size:

```
figure {
margin: 0;
   width: 370px;
   height: 200px;
}
```